# Android Dialog with standard width like AlertDialog

Tags: android, width, customdialog

I'm trying to create a `Custom Dialog`, setting my layout in order to customize it, but keeping the standard width.

In [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidAlerts/alerts1.png) picture we see a basic `Dialog(AlertDialog)`, which has a defined width. On  phones it has the full width minus some pixel, on tablet it has a defined width taht can be seen [HERE](http://www.samsung.com/us/system/support/faq/2011/06/08/about%20check2x.jpg).

The problem by using a custom layout is that the width shrinks to a wrap content of the layout like in [THIS](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-RqE5xMoWbN8/TbXTq89s9HI/AAAAAAAAAHA/lkG7YTIjsqY/s400/AndroidCustomDialog.png) picture.

How can i do in order to have a custom dialog, which uses my layout but behavies on size as a standard dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that after you set the content view for the dialog, you have to call:

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

And the dialog will have the same width as an AlertDialog.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you used LinearLayout for dialog. Try to set your root layout as RelativeLayout. It will solve your problem.

[Check this example in details](http://smartphonebysachin.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-create-iphone-like-custom-dialog.html).

Comment: not really, in portrait on my S2 it takes the full width. On landscape it's fine.

Comment: try using [this example](http://smartphonebysachin.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-create-iphone-like-custom-dialog.html). It elaborate you with custom dialog.

Comment: Thanks Sachin Shelke, it's perfect!